# Dask - GIL-holding

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I Have 3 machine

16 cores 32GB

One of the machine is the scheduler and the worker.

When I ran this code:

```
from distributed import Client
client = Client('ip')

import dask.array as da
x = da.random.random((400000,400000), chunks=(10000, 10000))

y = da.exp(x).sum()

y.compute()
```

It  ran fast and look effcient  :

[image]

But when I tried to read parquet files
It ran very slow and the warning message was:

```
distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 3.27s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
```

I tried many chunks size - `'8MB','16MB','32MB','64MB','128MB','256MB'`

but it act the same so I guess it 'GIL lock '

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
"files = 152 parquet files of 150MB in average"
ddf = dd.read_parquet(files,parse_dates=['event_time'],chunksize=chunk)
df = ddf.groupby('uid').agg({'article_id':'count'})
df = df.compute()
```

- distributed version - `'2.20.0'`
- pandas version - `'1.2.4'`
- OS -    `Centos7`

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: @jtlz2 - The problem was I/O - the data located on old network disk